# Filter array objects by latitude and longitude

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I want to filter all objects in an array where the distance is less than 200 kilometers.
I use [geolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) for that. Each object in the array has a lat and lng.
I use MapBox together with Geocoder.
If I search for a place here, the array should be filtered based on its lat and lng and only those objects should be returned that are within a distance of 200 kilometers.

But currently I always get all of them - no matter how far the place is

```
const updateHouses = (coords) => {
const lng = coords[0];
const lat = coords[1];

const copy = [...houses];

copy.filter((house) => {
  const dis = getPreciseDistance(
    { latitude: house.lat, longitude: house.long },
    { latitude: lat, longitude: lng }
  );

  const km = dis / 1000;

  return km < 200;
  });

  setHouses(copy);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

More information like where are you calling the `updateHouses` function it'll be usefull. But to me with that information sounds like you're missing a  `useEffect` somewhere.

I'd try this:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  const lng = coords[0]; const lat = coords[1];
  const copy = [...houses];

  copy.filter((house) => {   
  const dis = getPreciseDistance(
       { latitude: house.lat, longitude: house.long },
       { latitude: lat, longitude: lng }   );
 
     const km = dis / 1000;
 
     return km < 200;   
  });
 
  setHouses(copy); 
}, [coords, houses]);
```